# Why is the category of simplicial sets closed under finite inductive limits and projective limits?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I´m learning model categories. So, I have the following question.

The canonical example of model category, besides the category of topological spaces, is the category $\Delta^{o}Set$ consisting of simplicial sets. One of the requirements for a category to be a model category is that has to be closed under finite inductive limits and projective limits.

> **Question**. Knowing that the category of sets $Set$ all finite limits and colimit exists, why is it true that $\Delta^{o}Set$ is closed under finite inductive limits and projective limits?

Comment: Terminology nitpick : I think what you mean is not *closed under* limits/colimits, but *has* limits/colimits. "Closed under" is used for subcategories of a given category (for example : the category of abelian groups is closed under limits in the category of groups).

Answer (score 6):

The category of simplicial sets $\mathbf{Set}^{\Delta^\mathrm{op}}$ is an example of a functor category, and if a category $\mathbf{C}$ has all limits/colimits of shape $\mathcal{I}$, then the functor category $\mathbf{C}^\mathbf{D}$ has all limits/colimits of shape $\mathcal{I}$, and moreover such limits/colimits can be computed pointwise.  See, e.g., section V.3 in Mac Lane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician*.